# What is the purpose of quasi-variance?

Tags: statistics, variance

I have been looking for implications and why this would have ever been defined at all?

The best answer I found out there so far is that for one single data, the variance would be zero, which (makes no sense? - makes loads of sense to me) while it's quasivariance would be indetermined.

Does anybody have more ideas about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment:** The term *quasi-variance* is not widely used. 
According to what I can immediately find on Google, *quasi-variance* seems to
refer to $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$ as contrasted with
the *"variance"* $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2.$

In common usage, the first expression is usually referred to as the
*sample variance* $S^2$ of data $X_1, \dots, X_n.$ There are various
reasons for dividing by $n - 1$ instead of $n.$ One of them is that
if $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$ then the
expected value $E(S^2) = \sigma^2,$ the variance of the population
from which the sample was randomly chosen. If you have only a
single observation, you have no basis for judging the dispersion
of the population from which it was drawn.

Addendum: I defer to @L.V.Rao's mention of Firth's paper on
'quasivariances'. However, from the wording of the original Question I'm not
sure this is what OP had in mind.

Comment: Quasi-variances is due to David Firth. By searching Quasi-variances together with Firth will fetch you some useful resources. There was a  package called *qvcalc* in R.for computing quasi-variances.

Comment: @L.V.Rao. Thank you for this reference. Revised my Answer.